# Mexico states as a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, list

I searched the Internet for list of Mexico states, but didn't find anything. I found mostly US states or Canadian, but there is no good Mexico states list.

Does anyone have such a thing to hand?

Comment: This is not the kind of place to be posting stuff like this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is a Q&A site, not a personal blog or gist site for which this would be more appropriate

Comment: I _think_ this can be rescued - please post a question, and then self-answer (though it depends whether people will categorise it as a request for off-site resources). Edit: repaired. @Vaha, if you want to copy my answer as your own, I will delete my CW answer. However bear in mind you may get downvotes as well as upvotes!

Comment: You could have Googled.

Comment: @halfer, please do what you wrote. Thank you for editing my question!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the list of Mexican states as a PHP array:

```
 $mexicoStatesList = array( 
    'AG' => 'AGUASCALIENTES',
    'BN' => 'BAJA CALIFORNIA NORTE',
    'BS' => 'BAJA CALIFORNIA SUR',
    'CH' => 'COAHUILA',
    'CI' => 'CHIHUAHUA',
    'CL' => 'COLIMA',
    'CP' => 'CAMPECHE',
    'CS' => 'CHIAPAS',
    'DF' => 'DISTRITO FEDERAL',
    'DG' => 'DURANGO',
    'GE' => 'GUERRERO',
    'GJ' => 'GUANAJUATO',
    'HD' => 'HIDALGO',
    'JA' => 'JALISCO',
    'MC' => 'MICHOACAN',
    'MR' => 'MORELOS',
    'MX' => 'MEXICO',
    'NA' => 'NAYARIT',
    'NL' => 'NUEVO LEON',
    'OA' => 'OAXACA',
    'PU' => 'PUEBLA',
    'QE' => 'QUERETARO',
    'QI' => 'QUINTANA ROO',
    'SI' => 'SINALOA',
    'SL' => 'SAN LUIS POTOSI',
    'SO' => 'SONORA',
    'TA' => 'TAMAULIPAS',
    'TB' => 'TABASCO',
    'TL' => 'TLAXCALA',
    'VC' => 'VERACRUZ',
    'YU' => 'YUCATAN',
    'ZA' => 'ZACATECAS',
);
```

Comment: This list is helpful, thaks

Comment: Thanks, but you have some typos like 'DISTRICTO FEDERAL', it should be DISTRITO FEDERAL. Thanks any way.

Comment: Thanks @Koronos, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The line

'DF' => 'DISTRITO FEDERAL',

Must be changed to

'CDMX' => 'CIUDAD DE MEXICO',

The name of the city was changed in January 2016.

Normally in Spanish the name of different states have something called in Spanish (tilde or acento) to make an emphasis in the pronunciation, like México instead of Mexico, so if in your users are included Spanish speakers you should write it correctly in Spanish, I'll include both lists, one in Spanish and the other in English.

To help just if is necessary for another project.

Spanish array.

```
$mexicoStatesList = array( 
'AG' => 'AGUASCALIENTES',
'BC' => 'BAJA CALIFORNIA',
'BS' => 'BAJA CALIFORNIA SUR',
'CH' => 'COAHUILA',
'CI' => 'CHIHUAHUA',
'CL' => 'COLIMA',
'CP' => 'CAMPECHE',
'CS' => 'CHIAPAS',
'CDMX' => 'CIUDAD DE MÉXICO',
'DG' => 'DURANGO',
'GE' => 'GUERRERO',
'GJ' => 'GUANAJUATO',
'HD' => 'HIDALGO',
'JA' => 'JALISCO',
'MC' => 'MICHOACÁN',
'MR' => 'MORELOS',
'MX' => 'MÉXICO',
'NA' => 'NAYARIT',
'NL' => 'NUEVO LEÓN',
'OA' => 'OAXACA',
'PU' => 'PUEBLA',
'QE' => 'QUERÉTARO',
'QI' => 'QUINTANA ROO',
'SI' => 'SINALOA',
'SL' => 'SAN LUIS POTOSÍ',
'SO' => 'SONORA',
'TA' => 'TAMAULIPAS',
'TB' => 'TABASCO',
'TL' => 'TLAXCALA',
'VC' => 'VERACRUZ',
'YU' => 'YUCATÁN',
'ZA' => 'ZACATECAS',
);
```

English array.

```
$mexicoStatesList = array( 
'AG' => 'AGUASCALIENTES',
'BC' => 'BAJA CALIFORNIA',
'BS' => 'BAJA CALIFORNIA SUR',
'CH' => 'COAHUILA',
'CI' => 'CHIHUAHUA',
'CL' => 'COLIMA',
'CP' => 'CAMPECHE',
'CS' => 'CHIAPAS',
'CDMX' => 'MEXICO CITY',
'DG' => 'DURANGO',
'GE' => 'GUERRERO',
'GJ' => 'GUANAJUATO',
'HD' => 'HIDALGO',
'JA' => 'JALISCO',
'MC' => 'MICHOACAN',
'MR' => 'MORELOS',
'MX' => 'MEXICO',
'NA' => 'NAYARIT',
'NL' => 'NUEVO LEON',
'OA' => 'OAXACA',
'PU' => 'PUEBLA',
'QE' => 'QUERETARO',
'QI' => 'QUINTANA ROO',
'SI' => 'SINALOA',
'SL' => 'SAN LUIS POTOSI',
'SO' => 'SONORA',
'TA' => 'TAMAULIPAS',
'TB' => 'TABASCO',
'TL' => 'TLAXCALA',
'VC' => 'VERACRUZ',
'YU' => 'YUCATAN',
'ZA' => 'ZACATECAS',
);
```